# materializecss.com : Left SideBar Position Issue

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, css, materialize

I am using materiel css to design master page of my application.I need to position of sidebar to left so that I can use full width for content in content place holder.Below is existing pic of master page.I am using http://materializecss.com

[image]

Expected Layout:
[image]
Below is html layout source code.

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="nav">
        <nav>
                        <div class="nav-wrapper" style="background-color:#0055b7;color:#0055b7;">
                          <a href="#!" class="brand-logo"> <asp:Image CssClass="brand-logo" ID="imglogo" ImageUrl="~/abcLogo.jpg" runat="server" /></a>
                          <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
                          <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                            <li><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkdff" PostBackUrl="~/Policy.aspx" >Policy</asp:LinkButton></li>
                            <li><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton1" PostBackUrl="~/Support.aspx" >Support</asp:LinkButton></li>
                            <li style="text-transform:uppercase; color:White;"><span style="color:White">
                            Welcome <asp:Label ID="lblLoginName" runat="server" Text="RGR"></asp:Label>
                    </li>
                    <li style="text-transform:uppercase;">
                       <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/wtsLogin.aspx"  />
                    </li>

                          </ul>
                          <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
                            <li><a href="wtsPolicy.aspx">Policy</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Support.aspx">Support</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="container ">
        <!-- Page Layout here -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s3">
                <ul class="collection with-header">
                    <li class="collection-header"><b>TimeSheet Section</b></li>
                    <li class="collection-item" id="CreateLI" runat="server">
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkCreateButton" PostBackUrl="~/TimeSheet/TimeSheet.aspx">Create TimeSheet</asp:LinkButton>
                    </li>
                    <li class="collection-item">
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkEditButton" PostBackUrl="~/TimeSheet/PrevTimeSheetTest.aspx">View/Edit</asp:LinkButton></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="collection with-header">
                    <li class="collection-header"><b>Approvals Section</b></li>
                    <li class="collection-item">
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton2" PostBackUrl="~/Approval/Timesheet2Approve.aspx">To Be Approved</asp:LinkButton></li>
                    <li class="collection-item">
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton3" PostBackUrl="~/Approval/ApprovedTimeSheet.aspx">Approved</asp:LinkButton></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="collection with-header">
                    <li class="collection-header"><b>Reports Section</b></li>
                    <li class="collection-item">
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkJobCostingButton" PostBackUrl="~/Reports/JobCostingReport.aspx">Job Costing</asp:LinkButton></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col s9">
                <div class="row">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `.container` class which makes window width ~70%, try removing the `container` class.

[Link for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/e9hhg01e/5/)

Comment: Agreed. But in this case if i will resize window then main content shift below to side bar...not responsive